# What is the meaning of h-index for a journal?

Tags: journals, bibliometrics

What is the meaning of h-index for journals, especially those recognized Journals?

Comment: I could not quite understand what does a *recognized journal* mean.

Comment: I mean Good indexed Journals

Answer (score 7):

The h-index for a journal is defined is just the same way that an [h-index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-index) is defined for a person: the greatest value *h* for which there are at least *h* publications with at least *h* citations each.  Thus, for a journal, if it has published 1000 articles in its history, and 50 of them have received 50 or more citations, it would have an h-index of 50.